# Lots of problems (foreign key or no rows were updated errors) when trying to save complex objects in EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, insert, ef-code-first

I have a pretty deep object hierarchy in my application, and I am having trouble saving the entities. Depending on the order I do things, I either one of two errors:

> [OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.]

or

> [DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.]

Here is the classes I am working with:

```
public class SpecialEquipment : Entity
{
    public Equipment Equipment { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AutoclaveValidation> Validations { get; set; }
}

public class Equipment : Entity
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public EquipmentType EquipmentType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Identifier> Identifiers { get; set; }
}

public class Identifier : Entity
{
    public IdentifierType Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Location : Entity
{
    public Building Building { get; set; }
    public string Room { get; set; }
}
```

What I was trying to do was populate one `SpecialEquipment` object based on form inputs and already existing objects in the database and then save the special equipment to push all changes through, it looks like this:

```
Building building = buildingService.GetExistingOrNew(viewModel.BuildingCode)); //checks to see if building exists already, if not, create it, save it, and re-query
Location location = locationService.GetExistingOrNew(viewModel.Room, building); //checks to see if location exists already, if not, create it, save it, and re-query
EquipmentType equipmentType = equipmentTypeService.GetOne(x => x.Name == EquipmentTypeConstants.Names.Special);
Equipment equipment = new Equipment{ EquipmentType = equipmentType, Location = location };
equipment.Identifiers = new Collection<Identifier>();

foreach (FormIdentifier formIdentifier in identifiers)
{
    FormIdentifier fIdentifier = formIdentifier;
    IdentifierType identifierType = identifierTypeService.GetOne(x => x.Id == fIdentifier.Key);

     equipment.Identifiers.Add(new Identifier { Type = identifierType, Value = fIdentifier.Value });

}

EntityServiceFactory.GetService<EquipmentService>().Save(equipment);
SpecialEquipment specialEquipment = new SpecialEquipment();
specialEquipment.Equipment = equipment;

specialEquipmentService.Save(specialEquipment);
```

This code returns `Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)`. If I comment out the `foreach identifiers` OR put the `foreach identifiers` after the `equipment save` and then call `equipment save` after the loop the code works. If I comment out the `foreach identifiers` and the `save equipment` line, I get : `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "SpeicalEquipment_Equipment". The conflict occurred in database "xxx", table "dbo.Equipments", column 'Id'.`

So how can I make these errors not occur but still save my object? Is there a better way to do this? Also I don't like saving my equipment object, then associating/saving my identifiers and/or then my special equipment object because if there is an error occurring between those steps I will have orphaned data. Can someone help?

I should mention a few things that aren't inheritly clear from code, but were some answers I saw for similar questions:

- My framework stores the context in the HttpContext, so all the service methods I am using in my API are using the same context in this block of code. So all objects are coming from/being stored in one context.
- My Entity constructor populates ID anytime a new object is created, no entities have a blank primary key.

Edit: At the request of comments:

My `.Save` method calls Insert or Update depending on if the entity exists or not (in this example insert is called since the specialEquipment is new):

```
 public void Insert(TClass entity)
    {
        if (Context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            Context.Set<TClass>().Attach(entity);
        }
        Context.Set<TClass>().Add(entity);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Update(TClass entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry<TClass> oldEntry = Context.Entry(entity);

        if (oldEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            Context.Set<TClass>().Attach(oldEntry.Entity);
        }

        oldEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
        //oldEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;

        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

GetExistingOrNew for Building and location both are identical in logic:

```
 public Location GetExistingOrNew(string room, Building building)
    {
        Location location = GetOne(x => x.Building.Code == building.Code && x.Room == room);
        if(location == null)
        {
            location = new Location {Building = building, Room = room};
            Save(location);
            location = GetOne(x => x.Building.Code == building.Code && x.Room == room);
        }


        return location;
    }
```

Get one just passes that where predicate to the context in my repository with singleOrDefault. I am using a Service Layer/Repository Layer/Object Layer format for my framework.

Comment: Can't you write the code in a way that not every answer must rely on *guessing* what `GetExistingOrNew` does, what `GetOne` does, what `GetService<T>().Save(x)` does, what `specialEquipmentService` is, etc., etc., I mean, extract the content of those methods and show it here? I'm sure the problem is solvable, but you make extraordinarily hard to give a reasonable answer.

Comment: @Slauma Posted as you requested. The service methods are just your standard services in a n-tier layered application, and the Save method is just your standard generic repository stuff.

Comment: I also should mention that when I debugged this, the object appears fine. It is fully populated with everything you see here (nothing is return something unexpected). The Building , Location, Identifier Type, and EquipmentType properties are all existing entries. While the Identifiers, Equipment, and SpecialEquipments are all new. And I can make everything work if I save the equipment object, then add the identifers, save it again, then save the special equipment object. So I guess the question is can entity framework insert/update complex navigation properties? Or do I need to save each...

Comment: ..object first? It doesn't appear so  because I can add the identifiers to equipment before those identifiers are actually saved and that works fine, but I could be wrong because I first have to have that equipment saved before doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Insert` method does not seem to be correct:

```
public void Insert(TClass entity)
{
    if (Context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        Context.Set<TClass>().Attach(entity);
    Context.Set<TClass>().Add(entity);
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

`specialEquipment` is a new entity and the related `specialEquipment.Equipment` as well (you are creating both with `new`)

Look what happens if you pass in the `specialEquipment` into the `Insert` method:

- `specialEquipment` is detached because it is new
- So, you attach it to the context
- `Attach` attaches `specialEquipment` and the related `specialEquipment.Equipment` as well because both were detached from the context
- Both are in state `Unchanged` now.
- Now you add `specialEquipment`: This changes the state of `specialEquipment` to `Added` but not the state of `specialEquipment.Equipment`, it is still `Unchanged`.
- Now you call `SaveChanges`: EF creates an INSERT for the added entity `specialEquipment`. But because `specialEquipment.Equipment` is in state `Unchanged`, it doesn't INSERT this entity, it just sets the foreign key in `specialEquipment`
- But this FK value doesn't exist (because `specialEquipment.Equipment` is actually new as well)
- Result: You get the FK constraint violation.

You are trying to fix the problem with calling `Save` for the `equipment` but you have the same problem with the new `identifiers` which will finally throw an exception.

I think your code should work if you add the `specialEquipment` (as the root of the object graph) at the end once to the context - without attaching it, so that the whole graph of new objects gets added, basically just:

```
context.Set<SpecialEquipment>().Add(specialEquipment);
context.SaveChanges();
```

(BTW: Your `Update` also doesn't look correct, you are just copying every property of `entity` to itself. The context won't detect any change and `SaveChanges` won't write any UPDATE statement to the database.)

Comment: You sir are great, so it would be safe to simply remove the check for detached and attach from my .Save method? Or would that be useful in some other scenario? I used that because I found that on another question on here, but if I comment that out, it works as you said! Also the update method works fine, right now it's adding duplicate identifiers (I encapsulated the posted logic to be usable in both create/update scenarios) but that is just because my logic creates new ones everytime, if I also add a similiar `GetExistingOrNew()` for identifiers, everything should be gravy.

Comment: @DOTang: The problem is that it probably does what you expect in certain scenarios but it doesn't in other situations (like this one). It's just a difference if you call `Attach` and then `Add` or if you only call `Add`. Imho: Your `Insert` method implements a *specific* logic, not *THE* Insert logic, but you are doing it in a generic way. But the logic is not generic, it depends on situation. I would consider just calling `Context.Set<TClass>().Add(entity);` and nothing more as probably the most general way to implement an `Insert`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess? It can't have an ID if you haven't saved it and that's the root of the problem (since it works if you save first). 
Pop everything in a transaction, so if anything goes wrong all is rolled back. Then you don't have orphans.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523.aspx for how to use transactions with EF.

Comment: I mentioned at the bottom of the post, my Entity constructor populates an ID (they are GUIDs, not integers) anytime the new objects are created. Thank you for the transaction scope link but I would still like to know why I get the errors. Right now for it to work I am calling save equipment twice (before and after I set the identifiers on it) which just seems goofy.